# Cannot edit sudoers file - Cannot execute sudo

Tags: osx

I cannot currently use `sudo`. I also cannot edit the `etc/sudoers` file because `sudo` does not recognize me.

```
$ whomai
myusername

$ sudo visudo
Password:
myusername is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported

$ su - root
Password:
My-MacBook-Pro-3:~ root# sudo visudo
root is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

How can I get permission to use sudo?

Comment: In order to run visudo you need superuser privileges. If you have access to the root account then enter the *root* password, not your own and run visudo. Then you can add your user by username and grant them sudo privileges. From what I have read the root account is disabled by default on OSX. Enable it run su - root again. Be careful with the visudo file. If you are not familiar with the vi editor you won't be able to use it (assuming that vi is the editor that is used to open the sudoers file).

Comment: I'm fine with the vi editor, but thanks for the warning. So I enabled the root user and it still didn't work. Example updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already become root you don't need to use `sudo` again. So in your second example, after the `su root` just run `visudo` directly

```
su root
visudo
```